# Do you need to cook tomato puree?

Tags: tomatoes

I'm making a tomato sauce cold from tinned tomatoes and I was going to add tomato puree to thicken the sauce. Is it ok to use tomato puree without cooking it?

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify it? First, it's very confusing that the question you've used as a title is the exact opposite of the question you asked in the body. You accepted the answer "yes" but it's not clear whether that means "Yes it needs to be cooked" or "Yes, it's OK to use raw." Second, it's unclear whether by "tomato puree", you mean something like passata (essentially, tomatoes that have been blended to a liquid) or tomato paste (the result of reducing that liquid into a thick paste, which is sold as "tomato puree" in the UK and maybe other places, too).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While it is perfectly safe to eat tomato puree without cooking it, it is not generally recommended.
Uncooked tomato puree in a sauce can be undesirably sour and have a rather raw, rough flavour.

If you don't mind this then go ahead, but I would recommend simmering the sauce for at least another 10 minutes after adding the puree.

Comment: I completely agree, it's safe but blech. You could fry off the paste in a bit of oil in a small pan and then add it, but using it raw would not lead to a good result .

Comment: Tomato purée differs from country to country. In the US it is cooked but quite different from tomato paste. It can be used raw quite well, but is generally not preferred for fresh sauces because it tastes cooked rather than fresh (like fresh or other canned tomatoes).

Comment: In Germany it's usually tripple-concentrated and **very strong**. Still, I have friends who like to eat it with a spoon.

Comment: I believe this answer can be generalized to say that any canned food allowed for sale (by the US FDA which specifies heating during the canning process; e.g., at least 3 minute 250F for tomatoes) is safe without cooking, right?  Green beans, kidney beans, chicken...

Comment: @bobuhito - true, but (at least in the UK) tomato puree doesn't always come in cans, and there are foods that come in similar packaging that do require cooking

Comment: @simbabque the question is whether the stuff at hand here is closer to "passierte tomaten" or "tomatenmark" :)

Comment: @rackandboneman I guess you can drink the "passierte Tomaten" as well. It just doesn't taste very good. At the end of the day raw tomato is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I make tomato juice by thinning a couple of spoons of tomato puree and water. With a can of tomato puree, I can make about 2 litters of tomato juice. At a MUCH lower cost.

Comment: Rod, welcome! The first rule here is “Answer the Question” - unlike in many forums you may be more familiar with. So while your use of tomato puree is creative, do you really want to say: “Yes, one can use the puree uncooked. And I use it for...“? If you [edit] your post, it’d be much clearer. I also invite you to register for Seasoned Advice: This is a friendly and welcoming community and we appreciate all contributions. Take the [tour] and browse our [help] to learn more about how the site works.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, I assume you are talking about what comes in a tube or a small jar.

Comment: OK, I seriously don't understand that answer. The title asks "do you need to cook". The body asks "is it OK to use without cooking". You say "yes" - but yes to which of the two?